# How to connect sub-classes in Python?

Tags: python, object, subclass

I am new to Python and am trying to get more familiar with the object-orientated programming side of the language. I want to try to connect two sub-classes of a single class, using the constructor methods for the sub-class:

Firstly, I make the Employer class like this:

```
class Employee:        
    worker_list = []
    manager_list= []
    
    ## using a constructor to set class
    def __init__(self,first_name,last_name,salary):  
        self.first_name = first_name 
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.salary = salary
        self.email = f"{first_name}{last_name}@WHBC.com"
        if isinstance(self, Worker) is True: 
           self.worker_list.append(self)
        if isinstance(self, Manager) is True: 
           self.manager_list.append(self)
    ## class method for obtaining full name
    def fullname(self): 
        return(f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}")
```

I then created the worker sub-class:

```
class Worker(Employee):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, salary,department):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name, salary)
        self.department = department
```

And a manager sub-class:

```
class Manager(Employee): 
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, salary,department):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name, salary)
        self.department = department
        self.employees_managed = [worker.fullname() for worker in Employee.worker_list if worker.department ==self.department]
```

The attribute employees_managed works for any manager instances I create, but when I try to use the same approach with workers, I am unable to create a managed_by attribute for the workers.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you create the managed_by list in the same way you create the employees_managed list - it's populated at the time the worker object is created. Only manager objects that you created prior to that will be counted. Move it to a method and it will be populated according to the managers that exist when the function is called.

Answer (score 2):

Because `employees_managed` is defined by `__init__`. So, previous worker not have later manager's info.

You should use a function, or `@property`.

```py
class Worker(Employee):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, salary,department):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name, salary)
        self.department = department
    
    @property
    def managed_by(self):
        return [manager for manager in Employee.manager_list if manager.department == self.department]

class Manager(Employee): 
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, salary,department):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name, salary)
        self.department = department
    
    @property
    def employees_managed(self):
        return [worker.fullname() for worker in Employee.worker_list if worker.department ==self.department]
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpful feedback. I will explore @property further.